# Imagick combine images

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I use Imagick to combine few images into one, here is code:

```
foreach($this->images as $image) {
    $stack->addImage($image['imagick']);
}

$montage = $stack->montageImage(new ImagickDraw(), $placing, $this->resultWidth."x".$this->resultHeight, 0, 0);
$montage->writeImage($result);
```

i getting this http://prntscr.com/b54uwe

i'm trying to connect 2 images 1 and 2, also i need help, how to combine images withouw whitespaces between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to combine images withouw whitespaces between them?

The [`thumbnail_geometry`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.montageimage.php) should contain the width/height and offset (e.g. `WxH+L+T`).

To eliminate the whitespace, the third parameter would be ...

```php
$stack->montageImage(new ImagickDraw(),
                     $placing,
                     $this->resultWidth.'x'.$this->resultHeight.'+0+0',
                     0,
                     0);
```